# Python returns length of 2 for single Unicode character string

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, python-unicode

In Python 2.7:

```
In [2]: utf8_str = '\xf0\x9f\x91\x8d'
In [3]: print(utf8_str)

In [4]: unicode_str = utf8_str.decode('utf-8')
In [5]: print(unicode_str)
 
In [6]: unicode_str
Out[6]: u'\U0001f44d'
In [7]: len(unicode_str)
Out[7]: 2
```

Since `unicode_str` only contains a single unicode code point (0x0001f44d), why does `len(unicode_str)` return 2 instead of 1?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your Python binary was compiled with UCS-2 support (a *narrow* build) and internally anything outside of the BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane) is represented using a [surrogate pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF).

That means such codepoints show up as 2 characters when asking for the length.

You'll have to recompile your Python binary to use UCS-4 instead if this matters (`./configure --enable-unicode=ucs4` will enable it), or upgrade to Python 3.3 or newer, where [Python's Unicode support was overhauled](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-393) to use a variable-width Unicode type that switches between ASCII, UCS-2 and UCS-4 as required by the codepoints contained.

On Python versions 2.7 and 3.0 - 3.2, you can detect what kind of build you have by inspecting the [`sys.maxunicode` value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.maxunicode); it'll be `2^16-1 == 65535 == 0xFFFF` for a narrow UCS-2 build, `1114111 == 0x10FFFF` for a wide UCS-4 build. In Python 3.3 and up it is always set to 1114111.

Demo:

```sh
# Narrow build
$ bin/python -c 'import sys; print sys.maxunicode, len(u"\U0001f44d"), list(u"\U0001f44d")'
65535 2 [u'\ud83d', u'\udc4d']
# Wide build
$ python -c 'import sys; print sys.maxunicode, len(u"\U0001f44d"), list(u"\U0001f44d")'
1114111 1 [u'\U0001f44d']
```

Comment: you can use `sys.maxunicode` on Python 3 too. It is implied but it is worth pointing out it explicitly that `len(u'\U0001f44d') == 1` on Python 3.3+ (or a wide Python 2 build)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: sure, but as of 3.3 it is a constant there, as Python 3.3 and up transparently switch between ASCII, UCS-2 an UCS-4 storage for strings as required. And you really don't want to use Python < 3.3 anyway.

Comment: There is no narrow/wide distinction on Python 3.3+ (the internal representation is not exposed -- you don't care what python uses internally). The point that you could use `sys.maxunicode` regardless of the version.

Comment: I never said there was such a distinction.

Comment: Yes, that is why `narrow_mode = (sys.maxunicode < 0x10ffff)` could be used on any version (both Python 2 and 3).

Comment: My system is running Python 3.6 and I double checked `sys.maxunicode` value to be `1114111`, but still the length of this emoji/string is still displaying as 2 :_(

Comment: @ankit: I can't reproduce that: `python3.6 -c 'import sys; print(sys.version_info, sys.maxunicode, len("\U0001f44d"), list("\U0001f44d"))'` outputs `sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=15, releaselevel='final', serial=0) 1114111 1 ['']`‎