# Python length of unicode string confusion

Tags: python, unicode

There's been quite some help around this already, but I am still confused.

I have a unicode string like this:

```
title = u'test'
title_length = len(title) #5
```

But! I need len(title) to be 6. The clients expect it to be 6 because they seem to count in a different way than I do on the backend.

As a workaround I have written this little helper, but I am sure it can be improved (with enough knowledge about encodings) or perhaps it's even wrong.

```
title_length = len(title) + repr(title).count('\\U') #6
```

**1. Is there a better way of getting the length to be 6? :-)**

I assume me (Python) is counting the number of unicode characters which is 5. The clients are counting the number of bytes?

**2. Would my logic break for other unicode characters that need 4 bytes for example?**

Running Python 2.7 ucs4.

Comment: The client counts UTF-16 surrogate pairs.

Comment: When I tried running those two lines, it showed the length as 6.

Comment: @ssundarraj: see my answer; you are running a Python 2 UCS2 build. Use Python 3.3 or up, or get yourself a UCS4 build.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have 5 *codepoints*. One of those codepoints is outside of the [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) which means the UTF-16 encoding for those codepoints [has to use *two* code units for the character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF).

In other words, the client is relying on an implementation detail, and is doing something wrong. They should be counting code*points*, not code*units*. There are several platforms where this happens quite regularly; Python 2 UCS2 builds are one such, but Java developers often forget about the difference, as do Windows APIs.

You can encode your text to UTF-16 and divide the number of bytes by two (each UTF-16 code unit is 2 bytes). Pick the `utf-16-le` or `utf-16-be` variant to not include a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in the length:

```
title = u'test'
len_in_codeunits = len(title.encode('utf-16-le')) // 2
```

If you are using Python 2 (and judging by the `u` prefix to the string you may well be), take into account that there are 2 different flavours of Python, depending on how you built it. Depending on a build-time configuration switch you'll either have a UCS-2 or UCS-4 build; the former uses surrogates *internally* too, and your `title` value length will be 6 there as well. See [Python returns length of 2 for single Unicode character string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109944/python-returns-length-of-2-for-single-unicode-character-string).

Comment: Clients are indeed Java, how did you know they are counting UTF-16 surrogate pairs? Couldn't it be UTF-8 or UTF-32 too? Can I be sure they are *always* counting 2 codeunits, depeding on the codepoint it could be more? Your method of counting looks indeed more elegant. :-) Thanks a lot for this great explanation!

Comment: The counts would be wildly different if they were counting code units in a different UTF codec (8 in UTF-8 and 5 for UTF-32). Yes, UTF-16 either uses one or two code units, always, see the Wikipedia link in my answer. Java code can be fixed; see [JSR-204](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=204) and the [`codePointCount()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointCount(int,%20int)).