# Why can python iterate over strings of utf-8 but not emoticons?

Tags: python, string, unicode, emoticons

Consider this:

```
s = u"おはよう"
print len(s)
for c in s: print c
```

The output is

```
4
お
は
よ
う
```

which is what I expect

Now with emojis:

```
s = u"hi "
```

Output is

```
5
h
i

????
????
```

Why is that? How can I fix it? I have looked at various links before but can't get my head around it
Ideally I would like a solution that works both for japanese AND emoticons but if it is for ascii and emoticons only Im fine with it too

Comment: might be a version issue.  works fine in python 3.5

Comment: @user2539738 Well, Unicode handling is rather different in Python 3 vs Python 2. However, it works fine for me on Python 2.6.6.

Comment: Are you using Windows? Is it 64 bit or 32 bit Python?

Comment: Mac, python 2.7.10

Comment: It sounds like you have a narrow build. Please see [Python returns length of 2 for single Unicode character string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29109996/4014959) for more info.

Comment: Anyoway, thh advice is to upgrade to use Python 3.5 or 3.6 - there is no need to use an ancient version as Python 2.7 for this kind of work, and doubly so if you keep in mind that easier working with unicode is one of the strenghts of Python3.x series

Comment: (For example, te Python 3.x series no longer has the "narrow build" vs "wide build" distinction which is the likely cause of your reported problem)

Comment: I have installed python 3.x and it works fine. took me for ever to find a good reason to do the switch. Thanks guys

Comment: Well done, Thomas! It'll take you a little while to get used to the differences, but once you do, you'll wonder how you ever tolerated Python 2's string / Unicode madness. :)

Comment: Eeexcellent!!!!