# Python's regex module matches invalid unicode character not in string

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I'm getting a strange behaviour running this code:

```
regex.search(ur'([^\p{IsAlnum}\s\.\'\`\,\-])', u'\U0001f618')
```

This should match `\U0001f618`, which is the unicode representation of a kissing emoji. The result, however, is the following:

```
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 1), match=u'\ud83d'>
```

This doesn't make sense at all, because `u'\ud83d'` is not even a valid unicode character.

I expected this instead:

```
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 1), match=u'\U0001f618'>
```

What is happening here?

I'm running Python 2.7.13 on macOS Sierra 10.12.6, `regex.__version__` is 2.4.130.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Same python version, same regex version, output is `<regex.Match object; span=(0, 1), match=u'\U0001f618'>`. I'm on Manjaro instead of Mac, but not sure how that would make a difference. Maybe try reinstalling the regex module?

Comment: Same Python and regex versions, however, on Linux platform. Works as you expect.

Comment: Same Python and regex versions, can reproduce on macOS Sierra 10.12.6: `<regex.Match object; span=(0, 1), match=u'\ud83d'>`

Comment: I'm also running macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: This may help: [Python returns length of 2 for single Unicode character string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109944/python-returns-length-of-2-for-single-unicode-character-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @PM 2Ring, it is happening because Python is compiled with UCS-2 support (narrow range) instead of UCS-4 support (wide range). Because of this, Python internally (and incorrectly) represents `u'\U0001f618'` as two characters, which explains the regex result.

More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29109996/4111012