# How to properly iterate over unicode characters in Python

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I would like to iterate over a string and output all emojis.

I'm trying to iterate over the characters, and check them against an [emoji list](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vincentmwong/emoji_list/master/emoji_list/__init__.py).

However, python seems to split the unicode characters into smaller ones, breaking my code. Example:

```
>>> list(u'Test \U0001f60d')
[u'T', u'e', u's', u't', u' ', u'\ud83d', u'\ude0d']
```

Any ideas why u'\U0001f60d' gets split?

Or what's a better way to extract all emojis? This was my original extraction code:

```
def get_emojis(text):
  emojis = []
  for character in text:
    if character in EMOJI_SET:
      emojis.append(character)
  return emojis
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on Python 2.7 nor on Python 2.6 (and I don't have older versions at hand).  When I look at `list(u'Test \U0001f60d')` I get `[u'T', u'e', u's', u't', u' ', u'\U0001f60d']`.  What version of Python are you using?

Comment: This is how wide unicode character are [internally represented on narrow builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109944/python-returns-length-of-2-for-single-unicode-character-string). This should be fixed in python3.3+ where the internal representation [was changed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/)

Comment: Also, you can flip your loop and iterate over emojis instead of original string

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python pre-3.3 uses UTF-16LE (narrow build) or UTF-32LE (wide build) internally for storing Unicode, and due to [leaky abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction) exposes this detail to the user.  UTF-16LE uses [surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates) to represent Unicode characters above U+FFFF as two codepoints.  Either use a wide Python build or switch to Python 3.3 or later to fix the issue.

One way of dealing with a narrow build is to match the surrogate pairs:

Python 2.7 (narrow build):

```
>>> s = u'Test \U0001f60d'
>>> len(s)
7
>>> re.findall(u'(?:[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff])|.',s)
[u'T', u'e', u's', u't', u' ', u'\U0001f60d']
```

Python 3.6:

```
>>> s = 'Test \U0001f60d'
>>> len(s)
6
>>> list(s)
['T', 'e', 's', 't', ' ', '']
```

Comment: I don't know why but I don't think it will work for all unicode. Try `Test `

Comment: @TomWojcik Unicode strings are made up of Unicode code points, but some code points combine with others to make graphemes (single visual characters). Flags are made of two code points, for example.

Comment: TIL, thanks. So it splits correctly to (sometimes multiple) unicode representations, but I assume OP needed graphemes (emojis as expected by the end user).

Comment: @TomWojcik Graphemes are a complicated topic, but IIRC the 3rd party `regex` library has a `\g` that can be used. More than emojis can have multiple code points. Unicode just gets more complicated.  This post is 5 years old.

Answer (score 1):

I've been fighting myself with Unicode and it's not as easy as it seems.
There's this `emoji` library that wraps all the caveats (I'm not affiliated).

If you want to list all emojis that appear in the string, I'd recommend `emoji.emoji_lis`.

Just look into the source of [`emoji.emoji_lis`](https://github.com/carpedm20/emoji/blob/e35fc45168376b273d8d04630dbb7f46c4544989/emoji/core.py#L265-L282) to understand how complicated it actually is.

Example

```
>>> emoji.emoji_lis('')
>>> [{'location': 0, 'emoji': ''}, {'location': 1, 'emoji': ''}, {'location': 2, 'emoji': ''}]
```

Example with list (won't always work)

```
>>> list('')
>>> ['', '', '', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import re
re.findall(r'[^\w\s,]', my_list[0])
```

The regex `r'[^\w\s,]'` matches any character that is not a word, whitespace or comma.

Comment: That still splits the emoji into two characters:

`>>> re.findall(r'[^\w\s,]', u'Test \U0001f60d')`
`[u'\ud83d', u'\ude0d']`