# Looping over characters of unicode string showing unexpected code point

Tags: python, unicode, emoji

For example:

```
x = u'\U0001f622'
[c for c in x]
```

returns `[u'\ud83d', u'\ude22']` instead of the expected [u'\U0001f622'].

`\U0001f622` is an emoji, and since I have an emoji dict with which Im attempting to detect emojis in text, I need the looping to capture `\U0001f622` and not the combo `u'\ud83d', u'\ude22'`.

I'm using python 2.7. According to [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F622/index.htm) `u'\ud83d', u'\ude22'` is the C/C++/Java source code of that emoji.

How do I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: In python 3.5, its returning expected result `['\U0001f622']`, what version are you running?

Comment: 2.7.. I'm editing the question

Comment: Yes, It's a duplicate indeed. But that question was not answered..

Comment: @idoda: [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46714847/190597) is to use a wide python build or Python3.3 or newer. Is there some other aspect to the question that was not answered?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'll do that, thanks

Comment: @unutbu How is it done? The installation of a wider version of python 2.7? Can find it.

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: @unutbu no I'm using Mac. I saw thar rebuilding python on mac might be unsafe. I'll just change the code or switch to python 3 (It's about time anyway)

Comment: While it is possible to [compile a wide build python2.7 on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25112348/190597) you would probably benefit more (in the long run) by switching to python3. (Note though, it may take effort to [port your code base](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html)).